# Swift: create tableView using interface builder

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

I'm trying to implement a tableView in my app and though this was no problem with objective-c I don't know how to do this in Swift. Here's my code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
@IBOutlet
var tableView: UITableView

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.tableView.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
}


func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 5
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> UITableViewCell! {
    var cell:UITableViewCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as UITableViewCell

    cell.textLabel.text = "test"

    return cell
}
}
```

I also created a tableView with a prototype cell in interface builder. the prototype cell's reuse identifier is set to "cell". I'm not getting any error message but when running in simulator I get a bunch of empty cells with nothing in them.
Do you know what I've done wrong?

After testing a bit more it seems that both methods `func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> UITableViewCell!`and `func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int`never get called but I don't know what I've done wrong

Thanks in adnvace

Comment: You never specified what is or isn't happening, and how that differs from what you're expecting.

Comment: What error you'r getting?

Comment: sry you're both right. updating the question.

Comment: Are your `dataSource` and `delegate` outlets (for the table view) in Interface Builder connected to your class? Can you check these properties at runtime to inspect?

Comment: thank you so much!! they were not connected, that was the problem! how could I forget that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you forgot to set the delegate and datasource. You can do it in the code with the following lines:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
   super.viewDidLoad()

   self.tableView.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")

   // Set delegate and datasource
   self.tableView.delegate = self
   self.tableView.dataSource = self
}
```

Comment: thank you this helped a  lot! now I also have another problem: in the cellForRowAtIndexPath method I wrote the following code: `var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as? UITableViewCell
        var x  = 0
        
        if !cell {
            cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Value1, reuseIdentifier: "cell")
        }
        
        x = x + 1
        cell!.textLabel.text = "hi \(x)"` I would expect it to show me another text for each row (hi1, hi2, hi3,...) but it only shows my hi1 a buch of times..

Comment: Please don't write code in comment. Edit your question instead.

Comment: Yeah. That's correct that it shows always h1. You need to use the indexPath.row variable. There you get the correct number of the row.

Comment: @LordZsolt thanks for the advice. I will do it next time.
Prine again, thank you for you're help!